# Why while performing gradient descent we multiply the gradient vector with step size and not only the descent direction?

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, gradient-descent, neural-networks

When we perform gradient descent we adjust the parameters in the parameter space just by multiplying the step size with the gradient of the function. My question is why we need to multiply the gradient with the lear rate/step size and not only the unit vector in the direction of descent? why dont we divide the gradient vector by its magnitude?

Comment: The gradient shows where to go from the current point to get to a lower value. It tells nothing about how much we have to go, and the local minimum is usually not in the same direction anyway. A step too large and we could get past the optimal position and have oscillations, and possibly a divergent method. A step too small and we could have slow convergence. [Wolfe conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions) give a rule of thumb to have something not too bad.

Comment: For that we have the step size/learning rate! Why do we need the magnitude of the gradient?

Comment: The magnitude is only a factor before the normalized gradient. Removing it means you make it part of the step calculation. It changes nothing to the problem you have that you have to find a good step.

Comment: okay! Thanks..yes it makes sense. However, why in this equation https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4581807/1120672 the norm or the magnitude has been minimized? I dont understand why the descent direction has been found by minimizing the norm element for multi-objective optimization! Please take a look !